# QChart and using QGradients with accelerated OpenGL rendering

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

### **What is going wrong:**

Currently my chart works completely fine, it has gradients, and single colored series for example:

[image: colored chart with gradients and single colored series]

This works fine, but when I enable openGL acceleration (for more performance) on the 3 series using `fooSeries->setUseOpenGL(true)` the graph turns into this:

[image]

As you can see the color for the gradient series turn black, while the single colored series turns white. Also the Rounded Caps and Rounded Joins also seem to have gone. I did some experimentation to see what may be causing it.

### **Attemped fixes/experimentation:**

---

I color the series as follows:

```
// fooGradient is a QLinearGradient described elsewhere as an example.
QBrush fooGradientPenBrush = QBrush(fooGradient);
fooPen = new QPen(fooGradientPenBrush, 5, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
//There are actually 2 QPens for two separate gradients in the program, but this is just for the example.

QBrush barPenBrush = QBrush(QRgb(0xFFFFFF));
barPen = new QPen(barPenBrush, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
```

Then later attach these pens top their respective series:

```
fooSeries->setPen(*fooPen);
barSeries->setPen(*barPen);
```

Then they are attached to the chart. That's it. I will keep experimenting and looking at the documentation to see if I missed something, it may just be that the openGL acceleration only accepts solid colors, but it is said no where in the documentation that I can find. I'll leave a link to the setUseOpenGl documentation if anyone would like to take a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractseries.html#useOpenGL-prop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I seemed to have missed an important detail in the documentation:

> **Pen styles and marker shapes are ignored for accelerated series**. Only solid lines and plain scatter dots are supported. The scatter dots may be circular or rectangular, depending on the underlying graphics hardware and drivers.

I still wonder if there is a way to implement rounded corners and what not to accelerated lines.